# How to get window width within an iframe?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the width of the browser.

I have this code inside an iframe

```
alert($(document).width());
```

But it display the width of a `<div>` element instead.

I also try this code:

```
alert($(window).width());
```

But same results.

Comment: If the `div` element is wider than the `iframe` then that is the width you'll get.

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle or HTML code? that will help to understand the situation

Answer (score 4):

Try this;

```
parent.document.body.clientWidth
```

Comment: Oops..Updated!.. Thanks @Rory McCrossan

Comment: That appears to only work if the iframe is from the same domain as the parent document.